# Kali Linux | Social Engineering Toolkit | Email password incorrect

Tags: kali-linux

I recently started doing pen testing on Kali Linux and I've been having some issues with the software "Social Engineering Toolkit". I can boot it up just fine and use it just fine, however when I choose "mass mailer attack" (for legal reasons I am doing this between two emails I own), I am able to start doing the prompts. When I get to "email password" for the email I want to send the emails from, I input my password VERY CAREFULLY as kali won't show the actual password being typed. As it gets to the point of which I assume is where it logs into my account, it says my password is incorrect, even though it's correct. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: what it's saying]

Answer (score 2):

Google itself writes at https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255,

> **Less secure apps & your Google Account**
>
> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

It's not quite that simple, though, because if you go to the "[Less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/lesssecureapps)" page you'll find that it's no longer available. However, you can still use "[App passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/apppasswords)". An application password is intended to be unique for a single application to access a single section of Google's environment. For example, you could have an application password for receiving/sending email but it would not allow access to the profile or settings for your account.

What this means is that you cannot use a Gmail account for your email attack without setting up an App password. The process for this is detailed on and via the Google help page at https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833.