# Mutt Login Failed

Tags: mutt, gmail

I was using `mutt` for few months until it started giving an error: "Login failed".

When I do `mutt -d 5`

```
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] SASL local ip: 2401:4900:170d:264a:c146:ad26:5e83:fe0e;45008, remote ip:2404:6800:4003:c11::6d;993
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] External SSF: 256
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] mutt_sasl_cb_authname: getting authname for imap.gmail.com:993
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] mutt_sasl_cb_authname: getting user for imap.gmail.com:993
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] mutt_sasl_cb_pass: getting password for garv.lodha@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com:993
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] Authenticating (PLAIN)...
[2022-06-08 14:27:17] 4> a0001 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN Z2Fydi5sb2RoYUBnbWFpbC5jb20AZ2Fydi5sb2RoYUBnbWFpbC5jb20AYmhAZ3ZAZGdpdEAxJiU=
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] 4< a0001 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] IMAP queue drained
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] imap_auth_sasl: IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN AUTH=OAUTHBEARER AUTH=XOAUTH failed
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] Logging in...
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] 4> a0002 LOGIN "garv.lodha@gmail.com" "password"
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] 4< a0002 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] IMAP queue drained
[2022-06-08 14:27:18] Login failed.
[2022-06-08 14:27:20] mutt_num_postponed: using old IMAP postponed count.
[2022-06-08 14:27:43] mutt_index_menu[792]: Got op 164
[2022-06-08 14:27:43] Closing connection to imap.gmail.com...
[2022-06-08 14:27:43] 4> a0003 LOGOUT
[2022-06-08 14:27:43] 4< * BYE Logout Requested s1mb93885201jar
[2022-06-08 14:27:43] Handling BYE
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kali Linux | Social Engineering Toolkit | Email password incorrect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705218/kali-linux-social-engineering-toolkit-email-password-incorrect)

Comment: @roaima: No, Google has deprecated  "Less secure app access"

Comment: @roaima: Well, I checked and for free accounts the setting is already disabled.
https://imgur.com/WtLscVs

Comment: Suggested [duplicate answer updated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705220/100397).

Answer (score 0):

Google has deprecated unsecure login as of May 30, 2022.

Arch wiki mentions a solution ("Unable to login with GMail", https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mutt);
however, this does not work for me.

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: The information about Google authentication is good, but what is the intention behind the link to the Arch wiki's mutt page? (Please [edit] your answer as needed); thanks!

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/705220/100397